# How does git work with multiple projects/dependencies?

Tags: git

Our team is potentially migrating our TFS projects to GIT and I've ran across a few issues in regards to how I mock our current process using GIT.

Let's say I have Project_A and Project A has dependencies on Project_B and Project_C.

Project B and C are both standalone projects.

How do I make it so if Project_B is modified from within Project_A, then Project_B standalone will also be notified of updates.  Also inversely, if Project_B is modified from standalone, then Project_A will be notified of updates.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've looked into submods, subtree,subrepo, and git slave, but not really sure which one best fits.  I'm still new to GIT and adding the extra layer of complexity is causing a lot of confusion -_-

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is "not very well".  Cough ... BitKeeper ... cough open sourced now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is focussed on the concept of a "repository".  It has no notion of "peer repositories" or "child/parent relationships".  I would argue this is a Good Thing.

HOWEVER...

You can make use of Git "events" to notify other Git repositories - and respond with automated (script) responses when needed.

Look here:

- [How To Use Git Hooks To Automate Development and Deployment Tasks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks)
- [Customizing Git - Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)
- https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/

Of course, you can also create a git repo for your "system"; and have Project A, Project_B and Project_C all under that one repo.

It's up to you!

Answer (score 2):

Since Project B and Project C are both standalone projects, you probably want to create a repo per project and use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for B and C inside A's repo. Submodules can be thought of as references to other objects.

Nevertheless, if you want to merge all projects to a single repo use `subtree`, which will merge the repos into a single big repo. This is somewhat simpler but less modular, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Git's documentation explains this difference:

> Submodules are not to be confused with remotes, which are other
> repositories of the same project; submodules are meant for different
> projects you would like to make part of your source tree, while the
> history of the two projects still stays completely independent and you
> cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main
> project. If you want to merge the project histories and want to treat
> the aggregated whole as a single project from then on, you may want to
> add a remote for the other project and use the subtree merge strategy,
> instead of treating the other project as a submodule. Directories that
> come from both projects can be cloned and checked out as a whole if
> you choose to go that route.

I'd also consider using packages rather than submodules, if your language/framework supports this. E.g. for ruby you can use gems for dependent projects, which allows you to specify dependencies, supported versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hacky way:** Put all dependent projects into the same repository.

**Elegant way:** Create a repository for each project and then put all repositories into a master repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Google's Repo to organize your whole project. Repo is designed to manage Android codebase, which is usually composed of over 400 git repos.